# Hibernate JPA composite primary key error issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following class Interval with a composite primary key with 3 foreign keys, one to the entity Event and the other two to the Entity EventPackage. I have been trying to fixan error not being successful.

[image]

```
@Entity
@IdClass(IntervalPK.class)
@Table(name = "intervals")
public class Interval implements Serializable {

    // VARIABLES

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
    public Event event;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "start", referencedColumnName= "eventpackage_id",  nullable = false)
    public EventPackage start;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "end",  referencedColumnName= "eventpackage_id", nullable = false)
    public EventPackage end;

    @Column(name = "state", nullable = false)
    public int state;
...
}
```

This is the class Event which is related also with EventPackage and works properly.

```
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "event_id")
private int eventid;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "eventpackageid", nullable = true)
private EventPackage eventpackage;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event")
private Set<Interval> intervals;
...
}
```

This is de class EventPackage

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eventpackage")
public class EventPackage {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "eventpackage_id")
private int eventpackageid;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "eventpackage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Event> events;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "start", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Interval> start;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "end", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Interval> end;
...
}
```

This is the primary key Interval class:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(IntervalPK.class)
@Table(name = "intervals")
public class Interval implements Serializable {

    // VARIABLES

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
    public Event event;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "start", referencedColumnName= "eventpackage_id",  nullable = false)
    public EventPackage start;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "end",  referencedColumnName= "eventpackage_id", nullable = false)
    public EventPackage end;
```

Also I am using a JPA repository:

```
/** Interval Repository */
public interface IntervalRepo extends CrudRepository<Interval,IntervalPK>, IntervalRepoCustom {
}
```

And finally the error, I think there is some issue with the JPA Data repository:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find es.citic.cms.model.acq.Interval with id es.citic.cms.model.acq.IntervalPK@3; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find es.citic.cms.model.acq.Interval with id es.citic.cms.model.acq.IntervalPK@3
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:389)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.save(Unknown Source)
    at es.citic.cms.test.dao.AdquisitionDaoTest.testEventPackageDao1(AdquisitionDaoTest.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find es.citic.cms.model.acq.Interval with id es.citic.cms.model.acq.IntervalPK@3
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:690)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replaceAssociations(TypeHelper.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:886)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:868)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:886)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:868)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 37 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the critical information in your question is the `@IdClass`, `IntervalPK`. But it looks you mistakenly pasted `Interval` into your question where you meant to paste `IntervalPK`.

Comment: Are you Interval entity listed in your persistence.xml file?

Comment: Does anyone reach to the solution to this, I am facing the same error